# form post multiple elements with multiple inputs with the same name

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I have a form structure to save information about surveys and questions, this is kind of my code:

```
<form>
<div class=surveys>
Survey 1
    <div class="questions">
        Question 1
        <input name="value_1">
        <input name="value_2">
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
        Question 2
        <input name="value_1">
        <input name="value_2">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
<div class=surveys>
Survey 2
    <div class="questions">
        Question 1
        <input name="value_1">
        <input name="value_2">
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
        Question 2
        <input name="value_1">
        <input name="value_2">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
```

As you can see I have a form with many elements groups by divs called "Surveys", in which I have also many elements groups by divs as well called "Questions", the number of surveys and questions is defined by the number of elements I bring back from my DB.

This information is send to a controller (I'm using Laravel framework), and I would like to know what is the best way to send this data to the controller to manipulate it by the post request. I'm a bit confused because the inputs name have to be the same in every element, or at least similar, but i don't know how to identify the input so I can match with the question.

Hope you can help me, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
name="survey[".$i."][."$j."]['value_1']"
```

Where i is index of survey and j is index of question.

Comment: How can i get the data later in the controller? Which is the way?